# how to set return value in function query

Tags: mysql

Here i did currency conversion using mysql function. please below ,

```
CREATE  FUNCTION anycurrency_inr(book_id INT,pub_id INT) RETURNS DOUBLE
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE publisher_currency VARCHAR(60);
DECLARE org_amount DOUBLE;
DECLARE inr_amount DOUBLE;
DECLARE convert_base DOUBLE;
DECLARE convert_current DOUBLE;
 select publishers.currency into publisher_currency from publishers,books where    publishers.user_id=pub_id and books.id=book_id;
select publisher_currency into org_amount from books where user_id=pub_id;
IF (publisher_currency ='inr_price') THEN
set inr_amount=org_amount;
ELSE
select base_value into convert_base from currencys where base_currency='publisher_currency';
select current_value into convert_current from currencys where base_currency='publisher_currency';
set inr_amount=org_amount * (convert_current/convert_base);
RETURN inr_amount;
END IF;
END
```

above publisher table returns currency value into publisher_currency it may be as (inr_price or doller_price or pound_price or euro_price) and my doubt is how to pass return value in another query. here i pass publisher_currency value in currencys table. It show error as Result consisted of more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

This error is throwed because more than one row is returned by your request :

```
select base_value into convert_base from currencys where base_currency='publisher_currency';
```

And it is not possible to insert more than one value into `convert_base` variable

Comment: here i return inr_amount only.It is possible that above query will take as base_currency='euro_price'

Comment: base_value returns only one value when i pass (inr_price or doller_price or euro_price or pound_price)